# What to change the button color when clicked and hide when other one is clicked

Tags: javascript, css, shopify

[These Buttons are from the single html field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHJhW.png)

```js
function fn2() {
  if (document.querySelectorAll('#button_input').clicked) {
    document.querySelectorAll('#button_input').style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="button_input" onclick=" fn2()">
  <input class="quiz-panel-input" type="radio" name="{{ q_identifier }}" id="{{ a_identifier }}" value="{{ a_identifier }}" data-answer-trigger>
  <label class="quiz-panel-label" for="{{ a_identifier }}">{{ answer }}</label>
</button>
```

Comment: You can not nest `input` into `button`, that is invalid HTML to begin with.

Comment: Which color? The text color? If so `element.style.color = “newColor”`

Comment: But its working fine the HTML thing. If i click on the button the background color needs to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want?

```js
function fn2() {
  document.querySelector("button").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
```

```html
<button id="button_input" onclick="fn2()">
  <input class="quiz-panel-input" type="radio" name="{{ q_identifier }}" id="{{ a_identifier }}" value="{{ a_identifier }}" data-answer-trigger>
  <label class="quiz-panel-label" for="{{ a_identifier }}">{{ answer }}</label>
</button>
```

Comment: First thing with this input field I got many buttons. If a select other button then the previously selected button should automatically became normal.